# printf outputs rows, not columns

Tags: bash, array, printf

I have two arrays, which I want to print out in two separate columns from a single `printf` call. The following:

```
printf "%-${padding}s→  %s\n" "${lnFrom[@]}" "${lnTo[@]}"
```

Outputs:

```
dotfiles/git/gitconfig         →  dotfiles/hyper/hyper.css
dotfiles/hyper/hyper.js        →  dotfiles/nvim/nvimrc
dotfiles/nvim/warm_nature.vim  →  dotfiles/zsh/zshrc
~/.gitconfig                   →  ~/.hyper.css
~/.hyper.js                    →  ~/.nvimrc
~/.vim/colors/warm_nature.vim  →  ~/.zshrc
```

The three first lines are represent the `lnFrom` array, and the three last `lnTo`, they should be on their respective columns.

(`padding` in the printf statement is just a variable containing the length of the longtest string in `lnFrom` array)

Thoughts on how to fix this while keeping the single printf call? (not introducing any loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format specifiers don't match up to the number of elements present in each array. Once your array expansion happens, there are multiple words generated each needs a `%s` specifier to be matched up. So `printf` is just going to fill them with all of the elements of the first array, followed by all of the elements of the second.

Unless you know the exact number of elements that you are printing from both the arrays combined, you can't hard-code a static format specifier string. One way would be dynamically produce the format specifier array, by tracking the total number of elements that would be produce if both the arrays are expanded

```
count=$(( ${#lnFrom[@]} + ${#lnTo[@]} ))
```

and now create the array

```
format_specifiers=( "%-${padding}s" )
for ((i=1; i<=count-1; i++)); do
    [ "$i" -eq "${#lnFrom[@]}" ] && { format_specifiers+=( "  %s" ); continue; }
    format_specifiers+=( "→  %s" )
done
```

and now print the elements as

```
printf "${format_specifiers[*]}" "${lnFrom[@]}" "${lnTo[@]}"
```

If you had tested the above, it could contain an additional `->` between the part where the first array ends and the next one starts. It is because, we haven't identified the start/end positions of the array while creating the format specifier array.

You could do this

```
for ((i=1; i<=count-1; i++)); do
    [ "$i" -eq "${#lnFrom[@]}" ] && { format_specifiers+=( "  %s" ); continue; };         
    format_specifiers+=( "→  %s" )
done
```